# Type discrimination based on *any* element of an array (not *all* elements)

Tags: typescript, union-types

I would like to create a union type in TypeScript that can use an array as a discriminant, but have a specific type match if *any* element of the array meets some criteria, rather than *all* elements in the array.

For example, this should work because any household with a dog in it can specify breeds:

```js
const homes: Household[] = [{
  humans: 3,
  pets: ['cat', 'dog'],
  dogBreeds: ['mutt'],
}];
```

But this shouldn't, because households without dogs should never specify dog breeds:

```js
const homes: Household[] = [{
  humans: 3,
  pets: ['cat'],
  dogBreeds: ['mutt'],
}];
```

My thinking is that I should define my types something like this:

```js
type PetType = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'hamster';

interface NoDogHousehold {
  humans: number;
  pets: Exclude<PetType, 'dog'>[];
  dogBreeds?: never;
}

interface DogHousehold {
  humans: number;
  pets: 'dog'[];
  dogBreeds: string[];
}

type Household = DogHousehold | NoDogHousehold;
```

The problem with this is that `DogHousehold` will now only apply if *all* elements in `pets` are 'dog'. So it would work for `['dog']` or `['dog', 'dog']`, but not `['cat', 'dog']`. Using a tuple type could work, but I don't see any way I can create such a type without a predictable number/order of elements. The closest tuple type I could think of was `['dog', PetType?, PetType?]`, but this is awkward and only works if dog comes first.

Is there some way I can make TypeScript enforce type correctness like this? Or is this kind of type discrimination not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, we need a way for `dogBreeds` to know what `pets` is. For this, we need a generic:

```
type Household<Pets extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = {
```

And of course `pets` is of type `Pets`:

```
  pets: Pets;
}
```

Then we say, if `Pets` includes `"dog"`, add `dogBreeds`:

```
 & (Pets extends [] ? {} : "dog" extends Pets[number] ? { dogBreeds: string[]; } : {})
```

But first we check if `Pets` is empty. Otherwise if it is empty, `dogBreeds` would show up anyways.

We intersect the result of this check with the base of `{ pets: Pets; }`.

Then we can do it with cats too:

```
  & (Pets extends [] ? {} : "cat" extends Pets[number] ? { catBreeds: string[]; } : {})
```

However, we can't just use this type like this:

```
const house: Household = { ... };
```

TypeScript requires us to use a generic here, but then we'd need to duplicate code, which is not ideal.

To solve this, we need a wrapper function to do the inferring for us:

```
function household<Pets extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(household: Household<Pets>): Household<Pets> {
  return household;
}
```

And now we can use it:

```
const house = household({ ... });
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gVwM4QBZwDYBMA8AFCYJKCAD2AgDstiAlCAQyzkoxAEEAnThkHJYJwCWlAOYA+cVAC8UAN4BYAFBQokIgC4oBIgG5lAXygAyKAAodxMhWrEA2gF0oAfnlGtAImaiPJclRptQiQ7SgQAWwAjCE4nVzkobwAhTggIGi0BYTFHXSh3NwBKZVVTC2C-G0DHFzcoTwBjBmBfawDiS1CI6NjahKbgFLSMqCyRUVz8+qLlfSVlADMESgbgIRYodGQ0TFxLSvaoeiYWNi4ePjGxSTMtlHRsLXhth73g8UKnxHvd-Hf5EpQVLABCcSibb47bBzAzKZQNFgCCHbACMMmRP2wZkUKjUwS0jgANICAPQkqCUOBQAZQOCcRJwUSGQpzeGI4AYiAAJnRdyhWGxgPUSAJHgGHicDGICMoAmJuIGQ3SIqgRNJ5NOICgDGpzWZrKUMqRfIAzLzIa9BbjhaLvBLtdL2fLVMlUsqCQ5nVAybTWFqdd59XDDezOQAWc0vXZW1Q21Vi5oeQlQLyM+1S6lOwGKt0jNW413DFX51Q+yJwYCofVAA)